# Sending messages from windows service to desktop app on the same machine

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, windows-services, ipc

I need some advice about a scenario like this: We have a windows service, polling a DB periodically, say every five seconds. We also have a desktop application running on the **same** machine with the service. When the service fetches data, we need to notify the desktop app. according to some conditions (If the condition is true then it will notify, otherwise it won't do anything). In the desktop app. part, when a new notification is received, we will perform some actions like status updates, background color changes etc.

I did some research for such a functionality and it seems like I need to use WCF callbacks, hosting in the windows service. But I'm not sure. Is that the right approach? Is there any simpler way to do that? Any example will really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Hosting a WCF service in your Windows Service is pretty easy, and it comes with the added bonus that your client doesn't **have** to be on the same machine.

Since you own both ends of the connection and they're both .NET, I suggest you use a duplex net.tcp binding.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Nicholas, I think I need to work on this way. I hope I'll resolve this issue and provide a simple example about that.